# How Do You Add a Second "Posts" Menu to Your Dashboard?

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to create a second tab on my WordPress dashboard menu that has the same capabilities as the original Posts tab. I've seen instances of this where the second tab might be called "Projects" or "Teammates."

I'm struggling to find an article online that explains how to do what I'm asking. Admittedly, I could just not be searching correctly. Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a *Custom Post Type*, or *CPT* in short term. To register a new post type, you can use a simple code like this, which will add a new post type called `article` to your admin panel:

```
function register_my_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => __( 'Articles', 'text-domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => __( 'Article', 'text-domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Articles', 'text-domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Article', 'text-domain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Articles', 'text-domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Article', 'text-domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Article', 'text-domain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text-domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Article', 'text-domain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Article', 'text-domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Artcile', 'text-domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'text-domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text-domain' ),
    );  
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'articles', 'text-domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Website\'s articles', 'text-domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',        
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'category','post_tag' ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'article', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_post_type', 0 );
```

The first array includes the names and titles for various part of your post type, such as singular/plural title, menu's name, and so on.

The second array includes the features such as being included in search, being public, and so on.

For a more detailed information about this, check the official [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) page about `register_post_type`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch!